Windows firewall blocking IIS FTP connection - FTP port rules enabled
I've setup a Windows FTP server using IIS. The firewall port rules have been setup and enabled automatically during FTP installation, allowing FTP traffic on ports 21, 1024-65535 and 990.

When I try to connect from the server that the FTP server is running on, I can connect successfully with no issues.
However when I try to connect to the FTP server from a computer on the network, the connection times out, if I disable the firewall, I can then connect successfully.
I am testing the FTP connection using PowerShell.
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

What exactly were you doing using PowerShell? You have to edit the question to include such details, as you might be using the wrong approach.

Please do NOT crosspost: https://superuser.com/q/1851677/213663

I deleted and recreated the existing firewall rules which were created automatically during FTP server installation, which allowed a successful connection.
The only difference I can see is that the 'Program' setting is now set to 'Any'.
